# delay data cache

Tags: c#, caching, timer

I have a data caching problem,and am unsure of the best solution.

There is a list of clients in a checkbox, which may be filtered by some variables, creating different subgroups.
As the user selects (checks) a client, it is necessary for data to be cached in the background, which takes about 1/2 a sec.
However, the user also has the ability to 'Select All', thus checking all visible clients in the list. The data caching can be done on a list of clients, which then takes ~8 secs.

So my problem is this: When using select all*, or when the user clicks through fast enough, there's a huge performance degradation, as the data caching happens client by client, rather than as a group.

I need to delay the caching event by ~1 sec, in order to make sure the caching happens for the whole group at once, but am unsure of what the best way to do it. The obvious solution is to use a timer that gets reset with each client selected and after 1second will cache the data, but the constant resetting of the timer etc. feels like it seriously lacks elegance. Is there a better way to go about this?

- the GUI control 'selects all' by actually ticking all of them one by one, setting the event off one by one as well.

Comment: Sounds like you should be deferring this work until you actually need the data, rather than preemptively caching it so far in advance of needing it.  That said, I wouldn't call your proposed approach inelegant.  It's the same general idea you see with problems such as autocomplete when typing out a search.

Comment: Thanks John - didn't realise.

Servy - most of it gets displayed in one way or the other on the front end, so unfortunately that isn't a viable option.